npm install hangs on elasticbeanstak ec2 instance
npm install hangs with no error
having some issue with npm on AWS/EC2 instance provisioned through Elastic Beanstalk
also, the same installation runs fine on non-aws  ubuntu and macos
if I try to install some smaller packages like lodash, mongoose,  etc.. it works fine, however when trying to install express or other larger packages it hangs
machine type: t2.large and t2.medium (running amazon linux)
versions tried:
#1 node 18.20.4/npm 10.7.1
#2 node 20.18.0/npm 10.8.2
uname -r:  6.1.115-126.197.amzn2023.x86_64
disk: 8GB - lots of free disk space
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-96 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G   17M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  5.5G  2.5G  70% /
tmpfs           3.9G   20M  3.9G   1% /tmp
here is what top output looks like when npm install hangs - so, not short on memory
top - 22:36:46 up 26 min,  3 users,  load average: 3.87, 2.80, 1.68
Tasks: 126 total,   1 running, 125 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  5.5 st
MiB Mem :   7930.2 total,   3466.0 free,   1015.9 used,   3448.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   6585.0 avail Mem 

dmesg shows a lot of these messages
[ 1349.092480] INFO: task iou-sqp-3249:3260 blocked for more than 1105 seconds.
[ 1349.093925]       Not tainted 6.1.115-126.197.amzn2023.x86_64 #1
[ 1349.095186] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1349.097048] task:iou-sqp-3249    state:D stack:0     pid:3260  ppid:3247   flags:0x00004000
[ 1349.098968] Call Trace:
[ 1349.099781]  <TASK>
[ 1349.100549]  __schedule+0x1ad/0x530
[ 1349.101497]  ? _raw_spin_unlock+0xa/0x30
[ 1349.102529]  schedule+0x5a/0xd0
[ 1349.103434]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x11/0x20
[ 1349.104520]  __mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x372/0x6c0
[ 1349.105634]  ? io_submit_sqes+0x303/0x390
[ 1349.106644]  io_sq_thread+0x275/0x4e0
[ 1349.107616]  ? membarrier_register_private_expedited+0x90/0x90
[ 1349.108860]  ? io_sqd_handle_event+0xd0/0xd0
[ 1349.109904]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[ 1349.110863]  </TASK>

Here is the last bit of entries from the npm run log
600 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/binary-extensions 3ms (cache hit)
5601 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/binary-extensions set size:49673 disposed:false
5602 silly placeDep node_modules/ts-node-dev binary-extensions@2.3.0 OK for: is-binary-path@2.1.0 want: ^2.0.0
5603 silly placeDep node_modules/ts-node-dev source-map@0.6.1 OK for: source-map-support@0.5.21 want: ^0.6.0
5604 silly placeDep node_modules/unset-value has-values@0.1.4 OK for: has-value@0.3.1 want: ^0.1.4
5605 silly placeDep node_modules/unset-value/node_modules/has-value isobject@2.1.0 OK for: has-value@0.3.1 want: ^2.0.0
5606 silly placeDep node_modules/wrap-ansi ansi-regex@5.0.1 OK for: strip-ansi@6.0.1 want: ^5.0.1
5607 silly placeDep node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/expand-brackets is-descriptor@0.1.7 OK for: define-property@0.2.5 want: ^0.1.0
5608 silly reify moves {}


Could you try latest version of npm? npm install -g npm@latest

that did not work, it looks like it is a issue with a specific version of AWS linux kernel

this is happening due to a bug in amazon linux kernel 6.1.115-126.197.amzn2023.x86_64 that is provisioned by default for nodejs 20 environment on linux 2023 ,
fixed the issue by switching to a different kernel by replacing this line in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml
default_platform: Node.js 20 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023
with
default_platform: Node.js 18 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
